# Proving $\operatorname{Log}(z)$ is differentiable on $\mathbb{C} \setminus \{x \in \mathbb{R}:x \leq 0\}$

Tags: complex-analysis

This question is part of an assignment which I am solving.

> Question :define $\log(z)=\log|z| + i\theta$ where $-\pi<\theta\leq\pi$ and $z=|z|e^{i\theta}$ ($z\neq0$).
> Then prove that $\log(z)$ is differentiable on $\mathbb{C}\setminus \{x \in \mathbb{R}:x \leq 0\}$.

First I proved that $\log$ is continuous on $\mathbb{C}\setminus \{x \in \mathbb{R}:x \leq 0\}$.

Now, for differentiability I took
$$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{(\log|z+h| - \log|z|)}{ h} =\frac{(\log(|1+h/z|)}{h} ,$$
but This is an indeterminate form.

So, kindly tell me what mistake I am making and tell me how to rightly approach it in a detailed way.

> Also , part b is there which asks to prove that there is no power series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_{n} (z-c)^{n}$ convergent in $\mathbb{C}\setminus \{ x\in \mathbb{R}: x\leq 0 \}$ whose sum is $\log$ .

Kindly just give a hint for part b . I think b part will use a part and I could not solve a so b would be tough to do also.

Comment: When writing mathjax, you need to put dollars round the whole expression, not just individual terms in it.

Comment: Did I edit it right ?

Comment: Your difference quotient is not correct because the imaginary parts of $\log(z+h)$ and $\log z$ are not necessarily the same (so they do not cancel with each other).

Comment: @Gary I got your point . Can you please write a detailed answer on how to prove it differentiable . That will really help me .

Comment: I would just use $\frac{d}{{dz}}f^{ - 1} (z) = \frac{1}{{f'(f^{ - 1} (z))}}$. If you restrict $\exp$ into the strip $\left\{ {z: - \pi  < \Im z \le \pi } \right\}$, then it is injective and its inverse is precisely the $\log$ you defined above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Part a: Let $U=\mathbb C\setminus (-\infty,0].$ You know $\log$ is continuous on $U.$ You also know $e^{\log z} =z$ on $U,$ which implies $\log$ is injective.

Let $z\in U.$ Choose $D(z,r)\subset U.$ If $0<|h|<r,$ then

$$1=\frac{(z+h)-z}{h} = \frac{e^{\log(z+h)}-e^{\log z}}{\log(z+h)-\log z}\cdot\frac{\log(z+h)-\log z}{h}.$$

This implies

$$\frac{\log(z+h)-\log z}{h}= \dfrac{1}{\dfrac{e^{\log(z+h)}-e^{\log z}}{\log(z+h)-\log z}}.$$

As $h\to 0,$ $\log(z+h)\to \log z.$ Thus the denominator on the right $\to \exp'(\log z) = \exp(\log z) = z.$ It follows that $\log'(z) = 1/z.$

Part b: Suppose there is such a power series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n(z-c)^n.$ Note that $|z-c|$ can be made arbitrarily large while $z$ stays in $U.$ Thus the radius of convergence of the series is $\infty.$

For $z\in \mathbb C,$ let $f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n(z-c)^n.$ Then $f$ is an entire function that agrees with $\log z$ on $U.$ This forces $f$ to have discontinuities at each point of $(-\infty,0],$  just as $\log z$ does. That is a contradiction, showing no such power series exists.

Comment: Can you please give a rigorious proof why log z is injective ?

Comment: how does in last paragraph of your answer f must have discontinuity at each point of $(-\infty , 0] $ ?

Comment: Injectivity: Suppose $\log r_1e^{it_1}= \log r_2e^{it_2}.$ Then $\ln r_1 +it_1 = \ln r_2 +it_2.$ Equating real and imaginary parts gives $\ln r_1=\ln r_2$ and $t_1=t_2.$ Since $\ln$ is injective on $(0,\infty),$ we have $r_1=r_2.$ Therefore $r_1e^{it_1}=r_2e^{it_2},$ proving injectivity of $\log$ on $U.$

Comment: More general (and very useful) idea on injectivity: Suppose $f\circ g$ is injective. Then $g$ is injective. Proof: Suppose $g(z)=g(w).$ Then $f(g(z))= f(g(w)).$ Since $f\circ g$ is injective, we have $z=w.$ This proves $g$ is injective. In our situation we have $e^{\log z}=z.$ Since $z$ is as injective as you can get, we conclude $\log z$ is injective

Comment: Discontinuity: Just to take an example: If $z$ approaches $-1$ from above, $\log z \to i\pi.$ From below, $\log z \to -i\pi.$ So $\log z$ has a jump discontinuity at $-1.$ Since $f(z)=\log z$ on $U,$ $f$ has the same discontinuity.